# GCC: Why does an error in one line of code (comparison of string and NULL) cause a long list of error messages?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I've been curious about why one error can cause the compiler to generate a very long list of error messages. The following example is the result of an erroneous comparison between an element of a `vector<string>` and `NULL` at line 100 of `main.cpp` under GCC 4.8.1:

```
> g++ -g3 -std=c++11 main.cpp functions.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:100:24: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ and ‘long int’)
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                        ^
main.cpp:100:24: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iosfwd:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/postypes.h:216:5: note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
     operator==(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/postypes.h:216:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::fpos<_StateT>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:214:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:214:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:1031:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:1031:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:1037:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator==(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:1037:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:128:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
     operator==(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:128:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::allocator<_CharT>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:133:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_CharT>&)
     operator==(const allocator<_Tp>&, const allocator<_Tp>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:133:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::allocator<_CharT>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2486:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2486:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘long int’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2493:5: note: template<class _CharT> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_Tp>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT>&)
     operator==(const basic_string<_CharT>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2493:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT>’ and ‘long int’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2507:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const _CharT* __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2507:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘std::basic_string<char>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2519:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
     operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2519:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘long int’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:204:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
     operator==(const istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>& __a,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:204:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:64:0,
                 from main.h:16,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:1403:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:1403:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/x86_64-suse-linux/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:139:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&, const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&)
     operator==(const new_allocator<_Tp>&, const new_allocator<_Tp>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:139:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:811:5: note: template<class _Iterator, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)
     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:811:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:805:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)
     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:805:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226:0,
                 from main.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
```

This can make it very hard to understand the problem. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: It's not a long list of error messages.  There's one error, and then a lot of extra information about what the compiler looked at before deciding there was no function it could use.  This is much much better than the alternative (showing only the error message with no extra information).  But when reading it, you should start out ignoring the extra information.

Comment: @jgr208: No stack trace here, not even template stack.  Those functions don't call each other, they are all overloads which the compiler looked at, and is explaining why each one can't be used here.

Comment: BTW the base error message decodes to: "I can't figure out what `if (args[1] == NULL)` means.  The left-hand side of `==` is `std::string`, the right-hand side is `long int`.  And I have no rules for comparing a `std::string` to a number."

Comment: Compilers are friendly like that.  One missing '{' can generate pages of error gunge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an expression of the form `vec == NULL`, the compiler applies ADL to find an appropriate `operator==` to call. If it can't find a single one it outputs **all** `operator==` candidates found in all namespaces considered, and the reason they did not fit here.

One of those can look like this:

```
In file included from [..] main.cpp:12:
[..]:216:5: note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
     operator==(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^
[..]:216:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from [..] main.cpp:12:
main.cpp:100:27: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::fpos<_StateT>’
             if(args[1] == NULL) {
                           ^
```

We couldn't match the first parameter to the first argument as `std::string` isn't derived from any `fpos`-specialization (also `std::string` doesn't have any appropriate conversion operators, but that isn't mentioned here). If you defined an `operator==` that can't be found/called, wouldn't you like to know the reason from the compilers view? (Especially if you don't have a clue yourself)

This can be very useful at times. When it isn't, ignore it. In most cases C++-programmers immediately see and understand what causes the error message (and its enourmos `note`-section).

Answer (score 1):

This may help in situations like this (you got a large volume of template related message).
Whether your are using make or directly using the compiler, try to pipe the stderr to a file in my example

make 2> error.log

The use any editor open the error.log file.  Search for file name of the source code you wrote.  There should only be one or two lines that are interesting to you.  For example:

```
mysourcefile.cpp:51:20:   required from here
```

This is where the problem happened; look harder here.